# Writing a "Chessboard" function in Python that prints out requested length of binary

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop, binary

I have an assignment for my Python course that I'm struggling with.

We are supposed to make a function that prints out binary as follows:

If the input is:

```
chessboard(3)
```

It should print out:

```
101
010
101
```

And so forth..

Its a "simple" program but I'm really new to coding.

I can produce a while loop that writes out the correct length and amount of lines but I'm struggling to produce variation between the lines.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
def chessboard(n):
height = n
length = n
while height > 0:
    while length > 0:
        print("1", end="")
        length -= 1
        if length > 0:
            print("0", end="")
            length -= 1
    height -= 1
    if length == 0:
        break
    else:
        print()
        length = n
```

With the input:

```
chessboard(3)
```

It prints out:

```
101
101
101
```

Could someone help me figure out how I could start every other line with zero instead of one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
provide a [mre], and ask a _specific_ question about your problem. 
["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/843953).

Comment: You should edit your question to be a [mcve]. That includes your code, some input and expected output. All in text so they can be copied/pasted. It looks like `1` and `0` mean black and white? That's not immediately clear, so would be a good detail to add to your post!

Comment: @sc0rched that's good information to add your post, use the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68288491/edit) button!

Comment: Your function needs only two lines of code. First: `text = '10' * n`. Second: `print('\n'.join(text[:n] if line % 2 else text[1:][:n] for line in range(n)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, it is simple :

```
print("stackoverflow")

def chessboard(n):
    finalSentence1 = ""
    finalSentence2 = ""
    for i in range(n): #we add 0 and 1 as much as we have n
        if i%2 == 0: #
            finalSentence1 += "1"
            finalSentence2 += "0"
        else:
            finalSentence1 += "0"
            finalSentence2 += "1"


    for i in range(n): #we print as much as we have n
        if i%2 == 0:
            print(finalSentence1)
        else:
            print(finalSentence2)



chessboard(3)
```

returns :

```
stackoverflow
101
010
101
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I strongly advise you to understand what is written, and not only copy paste what is written :)

You're welcome.

Comment: I will look in to how to write for loops in range straight away and how you used the remainder as an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same kind of assignment, but as we have only covered conditional statements and while loops so far, following the same logic, here is my solution:

```
def chessboard(size):

 output_1 = ''
 output_2 = ''
 i = 1
 j = 1

 while j <= size:

   while i <= size:
        
        if i % 2 == 0:
            output_1 += '1'
            output_2 += '0'
            i += 1
        else:
            output_1 += '0'
            output_2 += '1'
            i += 1

    if j % 2 == 0:
        print(output_1)
        j += 1
    else:
        print(output_2)
        j += 1

chessboard(5)
```

returns:

```
10101
01010
10101
01010
10101
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def chessboard(x):
    i = 0
    while i < x:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            row = "10"*x
        else:
            row = "01"*x
        print(row[0:x])
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def chessboard(n):
    board = []
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(n):
            row.append('1' if (i+j)%2 == 0 else '0')
        board.append(row)
    return '\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in board)

print(chessboard(3))
```

Output

```
101
010
101
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used only conditional statements and loops as per the course curriculum, It is working fine but let me know if I can do anything to improve it.

```
def chessboard(num):
    h = 0
    while h <= (num//2):
        if num%2 == 0:
            if h==num//2:
                print("")
            elif h!= num//2:
                print("10"*(num//2))
                print("01"*(num//2))
        elif num%2 != 0:
            if h == num//2:
               print(("10"*(num//2))+ "1")
            elif h!= num//2:
                print(("10"*(num//2))+ "1")
                print(("01"*(num//2))+ "0")
        h+=1
```